# [hortonworks]: the Elephant in the room

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

There are two tags covering the Hortonworks Data Platform:

- [hortonworks-data-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hortonworks-data-platform) with 433 questions, and
- [hortonworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hortonworks) with 135.
- (Plus 45 [tagged with both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hortonworks%20hortonworks-data-platform).)

Ideally, users could suggest these as synonyms, but no users have sufficient tag score in either to do that. I've used the [synonym-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request) tag here anyway, in case a privileged user or Mod can do that.

Assuming we're all alone down here on our speck, I'm suggesting then that we Who's unite in a community-based effort to take on retagging [hortonworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hortonworks) questions to [hortonworks-data-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hortonworks-data-platform), with the attendant clean up and editing.

```
     .'`    `';--.___.-.
    /        /       \  \
  /|         )     qp|  (       I meant what I said,
 " \         '--' \  |--'     and I said what I meant,  
    \     |       /\=\  */     Two tags are too many,  
     |   /__.|  ||  '.`-(,      One-hundred Percent!  
     |__|_|  |__||    `'`
     `""`"`  `""``
```

Comment: [hortonworks] too much. We must ask him to slow down.

Comment: Horton must be the Elephant. He goes slow enough.

Comment: Cute elephant :). And... I might use that in a rap (just for my own fun) "I meant what I said, and I said what I meant, two tags are too many, One-hundred Percent!" If that's cool lol

Comment: @Jakar - just remember to credit Dr. Seuss!

Comment: I've added a note to the most recent questions tagged [\[hortonworks\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35081865/maven-is-not-using-proxy-for-remote-repositories-from-pom-xml#comment57961187_35081865), and [\[hortonworks-data-platform\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115786/hadoop-query-parquet-with-pig-for-tpc-h-benchmark#comment57961183_35115786), encouraging followers of those tags to review this proposal before we move ahead.

Comment: Thanks to "room" in the title, the related questions are all about chat rooms.

Comment: My name is Pekka and I approve of this pun.

Comment: -1 For jumbling up your "Horton Hears a Who!" and "Horton Hatches the Egg" references.

Comment: @femtoRgon Nah! Really? Where?

Comment: @Mogsdad - Of course, I'm joking, but... Your ASCII Horton is holding a dandelion as in "Horton Hears a Who!", but the "I meant what I said" line is from "Horton Hatches the Egg".  His famous line in Hears a Who is "A person's a person no matter how small". (my kids love these books, I can almost recite them from memory).

Comment: @femtoRgon - Well, look at that! My youngest is about to turn 16, so it's been a while since I read either. Nice catch!

Comment: "An answer is an answer no matter how bad." - apologies to Dr. Seuss

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This activity is complete - [hortonworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hortonworks) has been merged with [hortonworks-data-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hortonworks-data-platform).

Comment: point 3 is done :-)

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Did you do that? (The remaining ones were all set to be deleted automatically, edits may just delay that.)